# Evidence of Anthropogenic Climate Change

Tags: atmospheric-science, climate-science

I'm not sure this is a good place to ask this but I would like academic sources showing how atmospheric physicists account for where CO$_2$ in our atmosphere is coming from.  I would like primary sources showing how the IPCC for instance is able to make estimates about what percent of the CO$_2$ in earths atmosphere comes from where.  I hate that I have to say this, I don't want a political discussion about this, most people who study this seriously know global warming is man-made and dangerous but as an non-expert I want to see primary sources showing me how we know it's man made so I can articulate these arguments myself.

Comment: you realize this is likely in 100s of peer-reviewed research papers in the bibliography of the one of the IPCC reports?  The most recent report (from 2013) is 1500+ pages long: https://www.ipcc.ch/site/assets/uploads/2018/02/WG1AR5_all_final.pdf Good luck!

Comment: I think you mean "anthropogenic" rather than anthropomorphic...

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Fixed.

Comment: [This](https://skepticalscience.com/10-Indicators-of-a-Human-Fingerprint-on-Climate-Change.html) is an excellent starting point, as it identifies the peer-reviewed literature proving several key facts about ACC, including some concerning anthropogenic GHG sourcing. As @ZeroTheHero noted, there are many specific facts, each with different sources in primary research literature.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I read the fourth IPCC paper they report I found had no sources which was extremely frustrating.  I'd prefer if it had APA style citations to more easily follow up on specific claims.  Maybe I was reading a version produced for public reading

Comment: there’s all at ipcc.ch .The next one is due in 2022, and all previous ones are available.  The one I linked to was on the scientific basis for the conclusions, and there are 100s (likely 1000s) of references to research papers.  You don’t get to choose your citation style I’m afraid.

Comment: This is already partly covered by item #4 in the link from @J.G. (though the link to the study there is broken, [here's a current URL for the study in #4](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.1113692)), but anthropogenic CO2 has a different profile of carbon isotopes than CO2 from natural sources, so this is one strong type of evidence that the recent sharp rise in CO2 is mainly due to human emissions. See [this entry on realclimate.org](https://www.realclimate.org/index.php/archives/2004/12/how-do-we-know-that-recent-cosub2sub-increases-are-due-to-human-activities-updated/) for more.

Comment: @Hypnosifl's example has a simple explanation: natural sources use carbon that continually gains carbon-$14$ produced from cosmic rays, but fossil fuels are so old that isotope has decayed. So the disproportionate build-up of ${}^{12}\text{CO}_2$ is evidence of not only it being due to us, but also the world being old (although we don't get a very high lower bound on the Earth's age this way).